How to continue equation numbers in different subsections?
I want to continue the equation numbering in my subsections from different sections in beamer. The example is given below:
Section 1
Subsection 1.1
Equation (1-1) % where equation number follows the pattern (subsection-equation number)
Section 2
Subsection 2.1
Equation (2-1)

I used \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}, but this didn't work.
Here's the code for test document:
\documentclass{beamer}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
% Set equation numbers to include section and subsection
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{subsection}-\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
An example equation in Section 1, Subsection 1.
\begin{equation} \label{S1:EQ1}
    a = b + c
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\begin{frame}{Another Frame Title}
An example equation in Section 2, Subsection 1.
\begin{equation} \label{S2:EQ1}
    e = mc^2
\end{equation}
As the equation \ref{S2:EQ1} lies in First Subsection of Second Section, can I have this equation numbered as (2-1)
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Could you please add a test document?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up is confusing. If the second equation is supposed to be labelled "2-1", it must be the case that the label's first component is the section number, not the subsection number (which, according to your posting, is "1", not "2"). Please clarify what it is that you're trying to achieve.

Thanks for your responses, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.
I edited my question and put the code for the test document.

@MuhammadUsman As Mico said, I think you need \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{equation}}
